# Affect groups() to panda column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe and I want to split a column with a regular expression and create new columns in this dataframe :

```
data = ["a:b-c","d:e-f"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['expr'])

>>> df
   expr
0  a:b-c
1  d:e-f
```

And here is what I want :

```
>>> df
    expr one two three
0  a:b-c   a   b     c
1  d:e-f   d   e     f
```

I tried this command but with the error :

```
>>> df["one"], df["two"], df["three"] = df["expr"].apply(lambda x: re.match("^(.*):(.*)-(.*)$",x).groups())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

How to have the expected result ? Thanx

Answer (score 1):

```
data = ["a:b-c","d:e-f"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['expr'])
df
```

```
    expr
0  a:b-c
1  d:e-f
```

```
df['one'], df['two'], df['three'] = df['expr'].str.split(':|-', expand=True)
df
```

```
    expr one two three
0  a:b-c   a   b     c
1  d:e-f   d   e     f
```

Comment: Thanx, ok it works but I want to do it with my example (apply and lambda) because my regexp is more complicated and I need to use re.match...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).